# Block Google Chrome Task Manager with Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I am looking for a way to block the native task manager that displays the currently running processes in Google Chrome with a browser extension. The Task Manager is accessed by opening the wrench/spanner and selecting "View background pages (##)" or through a tab by navigating to "chrome://tasks". Using an extension to block access to the Task Manager through a tab is relatively simple. However, does anyone know if there is a way, with only an extension, to deny access to this pop-up Task Manager window from the Chrome options menu?

Comment: why would you want to do this? it seems to me to be a bad idea.

Comment: The idea is to create a proof-of-concept extension that demonstrates that an extension can be created that cannot be removed.

Comment: @user1155271: So lets hope it isn't possible! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Writing a [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html) is probably going to be your only option.

Comment: Thanks! Might be a little out-of-my-scope for what I'm trying to do, though.